# How to serialize execution of array of observables

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I have a validation process which validates data in the table row by row. Because each row validation uses a shared resource, access to it must be serialized.

```
public validate():Observable<boolean>{
    const rowValidations:Observable<boolean>[] = dataRows.map(row=>this.validateSingleRow(row);
    return forkJoin(...rowValidations).pipe(
      map(results=>results.every(r=>r))
    )
}
```

If I understand correctly, `forkJoin` will not wait for each observable to finish before subscribing to the next one like `concat` would so that will probably fail. `concat` on the other hand serializes all the observables into a single stream.

How can I get a subscription order like with `concat` but have an array of results of each observable like with `forkJoin` effectively synchronizing execution of each inner observable (like Javas `synchronzied validateSingleRow`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, if you know that each `this.validateSingleRow(row)` will always emit only once you can use `toArray()`:

```
concat(...rowValidations).pipe(
  toArray(),
);
```

`concat` will guarantee correct order and `toArray()` will collect all emissions into a single array and reemit it after the source Observable completes.

Otherwise, if `validateSingleRow` might emit multiple times and you always want only its last value you could use `scan`:

```
const indexedRowValidations = rowValidations.map((o, index) => o.pipe(
  map(result => [index, result]),
));

concat(...indexedRowValidations ).pipe(
  scan((acc, [index, result]) => {
    acc[index] = result;
    return acc;
  }, {}),
  takeLast(1),
);
```

(I didn't test it but I believe you get the idea :)).

Comment: Hah look I just wrote that a moment before you did. using concat with toArray is the way to go in my case indeed .

Comment: Ill accept that as it would be probably a BM to accept my own answer;)

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this do the trick for you?

```
class SomeClass {
  dataRows = [1, 2, 3];

  public validate(): Observable<boolean[]> {
    return this.resolveSequentially(this.dataRows);
  }

  private validateSequentially<T>([cur, ...obs]: T[]): Observable<boolean[]> {
    return cur
      ? this.validateSingleRow(cur).pipe(
          switchMap((x) =>
            this.validateSequentially(obs).pipe(map((arr) => [x, ...arr]))
          )
        )
      : of([]);
  }

  // Mock
  private validateSingleRow(cur: any) {
    console.log(`Validating ${cur}...`);
    return of(Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) === 1).pipe(
      delay(1000),
      tap((x) => console.log(`Result: ${x}`))
    );
  }
}

const obj = new SomeClass();

obj.validate().subscribe(console.log);
```

[StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-o6jjsn?file=index.ts)

Comment: Looks interesting. Could it be done with `expand` operator?

Comment: Yes probably but it would need to keep the state outside of it and to have impure (with side-effects) callbacks. Otherwise it's impossible to implement the exit condition

Comment: I just did concat(...myCallbacks).pipe(toArray()) to get `concat` behavior with `forkJoin` alike result. I didnt even know that toArray is there.....

Comment: Is it what you need? if you do `concat(...myCallbacks)` that means you have already built an array of Observables. I thought you needed to build them on the fly (calling `validateSingleRow` after the previous item is validated).

Comment: Then I think your solution will cancel the need of using `defer` in my cases. And no, row validation isolated thus all observables can be created beforehand (but have to be defered) I is still interesting, thus upvote

Comment: OK I misunderstood your question then. Thanks for the vote anyway

Comment: Sure, I thought it is clear in the code as snippet contains Observable[] already. Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 0):

Solution that meets my requirement is simpler than one might think. I have used `concat` with `toArray()` like this

```
const rowValidations:Observable<boolean>[] = dataRows.map(row=>defer(()=>this.validateSingleRow(row));
return concat(...rowValidations).pipe(
  toArray(),
  map(results=>results.every(r=>r))
)
```

so `validateSingleRow` is executed one by one and `toArray` transforms boolean stream into array of boolean.